# Should every business object be a service?

Tags: .net, wcf, web-services, asmx

I know performance can be an issue with web services when you compare them to direct code. But with SOA on the rise, I have to wonder if I should be planning to make every business object in my apps into a web service, either WCF or .asmx.

The improvements to WCF in .NET 4 are definitely making me give is a second look.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Regardless of 'the future', cool new technologies and the like, one principle never goes out of date:  Simplicity.

My general approach is to keep things as simple as possible.  The dev tools we have today makes it delightfully easy to 'upgrade' a normal business object into a webservice when you need to.

Just a few less wires inside the box that are not needed.  Plus a free performance boost :)

Answer (score 0):

Regardless of dogma, the correct answer is given by the answer to "does it make sense?"

Does it make sense to make your `Employee` business object available as a service? Maybe so. Does it make sense to have your `WarehouseShelfLocationArchive` business object available as a service? Maybe not. If not, it's foolish to do so only because it's fashionable.

Answer (score 0):

@gabe is right that you need to make sure that making objects services makes sense. However, I've also found that once you build a service, others will consume it. I've seen this over and over again in the services I've written: "if you build it, they will come".

Answer (score 0):

SOA is about independent systems talking to other independent systems.  If you have a scenario where one system needs to know about the actions or data of another system, a service might be the answer, but not every object you ever create will not need to be consumed via a service. And all the other guys are exactly correct. Does it make sense? and Is it simple?